# Enabling keyboard lights in Fedora 35

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, sony-vaio, backlight

I am running Fedora on a (by now pretty old) Sony Vaio notebook, and the keyboard lights stopped working after an update many years ago. I now upgraded to Fedora 35 to install the vaio-control-center, but it can not be launched on my computer because:

```
[martin@localhost ~]$ vaio-control-center
open_file: can't open /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight_timeout: No such file or directory
```

I couldn't find any mention of this error anywhere, so I don't believe this is fixable.

Is there a way to turn on the keyboard light manually? I need it so rarely that turning it on and off in terminal would also do the trick for me. I found a method for this for Ubuntu, but it doesn't work in Fedora.

I know the lighting does work, because the lights do turn on when I touch a key during bootup. But once Fedora is running, the lights go out and stay out, so I am certain it has something to do with the OS setting, not a hardware issue.

My goal is to be able to get the lights on when I want to type in the dark. All three possible solutions would work for me.

1. Is there a fix for the kbd_backlight_timeout issue?
2. Can Fedora 35 be configured through terminal to turn the lights on for a few seconds when keys are pressed?
3. Can the lights be forced on and off through a terminal command?

Comment: If you suspend to RAM and then resume, does the keyboard backlight work normally?  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1583752

Comment: Yes, it does. Seems like a working workaround, thanks. I'm still interested in a more permanent fix, if there is one, though.

Comment: Yeah, that workaround is pretty lame and probably lucky that it was discovered. Should I post it as an "answer"?  I Googled around and looked at bugzilla but I didn't find a permanent solution unfortunately.  Maybe somebody else can find something?  I wonder if Sony has addressed this?

Comment: I beleive this would be an issue with Fedora. There even is a software package with the Vaio Control Center for Fedora, which supposedly can make the settings, but  for some reason it doesn't install on my computer. Posting the the  sleep/hybernate workaround as an answer is probably more visible than as this tiny footnote for anyone looking this up in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue with RedHat/Fedora.  You can read about at their [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1583752) website.

Interestingly there is a "hacky" workaround to enable the Sony Vaio keyboard backlight functionality.  If you suspend to RAM and then resume, the backlight may start to act normally.